# How can an abstract class be executed if it cannot be instantiated

Tags: php, abstract-class

I was trying out some OOP programming in PHP and when I instantiated a class, it generated an error saying that that class needs to be abstract.

When does a class need to be abstract?  And how can abstract classes be called? Thanks

Comment: Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)

Comment: You might want to give an example of your class and the exact error message, you're definitely missing something here.

Comment: I don't actually remember, I was trying to understand some terms and other oop stuff so I just made classes called Spoon and Fork which implement an interface called Utensils. Both spoon and fork had only a public property $dirt. both had functions called useit and cleanit. That's all I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a situation where you would get an error that a class needs to be abstract. Its more likely that you got an error when trying to instantiate an abstract class. Something along the lines of "Cannot create instance of an abstract class".

Abstract classes cannot not be instantiated directly. Instead they are extended by a child class (a concrete class) that can be instantiated. So an abstract class is like a template that provides some common functionality for other sub-classes. Usually it includes some abstract methods that the child classes must implement.

Comment: If an abstract class can only be inherited(extended), why bother to make it abstract?

Comment: An example that I have actually used in the past. You have a `Parser` class that is abstract and defines some methods that every parser will need. However it leaves the method `parse` as abstract. So the `CsvParser` and `XmlParser` subclasses extend the `Parser` class and implement the `parse` method.